Which Bluetooth Module can I use with Arduino Micro?
I am building a HID (mouse) using Arduino Micro. I want the mouse to communicate with the PC wirelessly. I am wondering which Bluetooth module works for me either HC-05,06 or any other?

the question is not opinion based. please share as an answer your experience with a module for BLE HID with an AVR based MCU.

It would be difficult to beat the price of a COTS Bluetooth mouse. If that's not your goal, then, perhaps, your next step might be to search if an HC-05 can support the HID protocol. Or, if that's not possible, if the Atmel Mega can. I might be wrong, but I think that would be the tricky bit in your project.

The HC-05 should certainly allow you to communicate with an Arduino Micro via the provided hardware serial port (Tx/Rx pins).  Here's a link to my blog post about doing this with an Arduino Uno (should be the same except possibly pin # differences).

Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Isn't that what links are for - to lessen the requirement to repeat stuff, or summarize it in a way that leaves out important details?

I think the linked post answers that
